# Node v15.5.0 doesn't read command line flags

Tags: node.js, command-line

I am trying to make a cli that uses flags as settings/options. It's all working, except it doesn't read the `argv`s. Here's what I'm doing now:

```js
console.log(process.argv)
console.log(process.execArgv)
```

And here's what I get in the console:

```
C:\Users\divinelemon\Downloads\Programming\Node.js\client>npm start --output=file

> npm-generator@1.0.0 start C:\Users\divinelemon\Downloads\Programming\Node.js\client
> node index.js

[
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\divinelemon\\Downloads\\Programming\\Node.js\\client\\index.js'
]
[]
```

As you can see, I clearly ran the script with the flag: `--output=file` but nothing shows up. Does this have something to do with the newest update of Node.js?

### EDIT:

I used the link above and thought this was the best for my use case:

```js
process.env.npm_config_<flag name>
```

Which can be used like this:

```
$ node index.js --foo=bar
```

This is what your index.js file would look like:

```js
console.log(process.env.npm_config_foo)
//=> 'bar'
```

Comment: @Deadron yes, thanks so much! Feel free to mark this as a duplicate.